# How to query across a nested resource with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
User (id)
UserRoom (user_id, room_id, banned(boolean)
Room (id, uuid)
```

Right now I can get all of a user's rooms as follows:

```
current_user.rooms.find_all_by_uuid(@requested_ids)
```

What I would like to do is expand this to only show rooms that aren't banned (banned => false).

What's the right rails way to add that condition to the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditions like so:

```
current_user.rooms.find :all, :conditions => { :uuid => @requested_id, :banned => false }
```

Using @requested_ids as an array (probably not as elegant):

```
current_user.rooms.find :all, :conditions => ["uuid IN (?) AND banned=0", @requested_ids]
```

Comment: Thanks but it's @requested_ids which is a list of IDs not just one ?

Comment: In that case you can use an sql condition. Edited.